# Два сайта на одном IP

Tags: apache, ubuntu, маршрутизация, сервер

На Ubuntu server 14.04 настроил виртуальные хосты. На сервере всё работает, каждый виртуальный хост отображает страницы со своей директории.

На внешней машине настроил:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
82.143.270.70 site1.server www.site1.server
```

IP (в статье) изменил на выдуманный. Однако в браузере отображается дефолтная страница апача. Что ещё необходимо сделать, чтобы отображался нужный виртуальный хост?

P.S.
Я понимаю, что кроме меня на него никто попасть не сможет. Мне он нужен только для тестирования и разработки. Позже прикручу к серверу домен, сейчас в этом нет необходимости.

Как я настраивал вебсервер - [смотреть](http://sitefresh.net/articles/25-nastroika-veb-servera-ubuntu-server-14-04.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

См. настройки конфигурации виртуальных хостов изменить только:

в место:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.1.1:80>
```

это:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

При использовании IP адреса (я так полагаю) необходимо произвести маршрутизацию на сервере. Если кто распишет этот вариант буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

У apache еще надо создать конфигурацию virtualhost, чтобы он мог отвечать правильно на ваши arp запросы. Если Ubuntu, то там папки sites-available sites-enabled. Создаете в sites-available конфигурацию и через a2ensite включаете. Если другие линуксы или unix, то же самое надо создать VirtualHost и перезагрузить апач.

**UPD**
У вас неправильно настроены VirtualHost, если выдается дефолтная страница! 
В sites-enabled должны быть ссылки на виртуальные хосты, если они есть, перестартуйте апач, если нету, то через a2ensite создайте их.

Comment: По этому адресу выдаётся основной сайт сервера - дефолтная страница апача. А что именно я сделал неправильно, я и пытаюсь понять.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: там есть ссылки, созданные через a2ensite. Повторюсь на всякий пожарный. Когда нахожусь на сервере, через тививер открываю браузер, то там всё работает.

Comment: :) как бы вообще тогда непонятно. Я к примеру в своем хосте (на компе котором работаю) прописываю в файл hosts что допустим мой сервер
192.168.0.11 имеет адрес PHONE1 и PHONE2 естественно что он - сервер будет отвечать на оба. т.к. я физически это прописал у хоста с которого запрашиваю. Далее я должен сказать серверу в данном случаи апачу что если у меня просят такой адрес значит ответь так, если такой значит так. Смотирте включены ли там у вас эти виртуальные хосты. Не может быть чтобы на сервере работало, а на компе нет. Апач неполучает правильный запрос или просто не смотрит на VirtualHost

Comment: есть предположение, что проблема с днс. Сервер ведь у меня не имеет домена, только IP. ХЗ что делать, буду пока работать только с дефолтным адресом, позже домен прикручу, а там посмотрим.

Comment: ДНС у вас заменяет файл хостс. Надо видеть ваши конфиги, чтобы понимать, что у вас не так! Если вы все правильно настроили, то должно обязательно работать.

Answer (score 1):

На [apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org) давно всё расписали: [тырц](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)